# Distinguishability of classical particles with magnetic moment

Tags: statistical-mechanics, partition-function, magnetic-moment

Given a system of $N$ identical particles, under external field $\vec{H}$ in fixed volume $V$ and each particle has energy given by $\epsilon_{\vec{p},H}=\dfrac{\vec{p}^2}{2m} + \mu_BH\sigma$, where $\sigma \in\lbrace-1,0,1\rbrace$, I want to calculate the partition function of the system.

My reasoning is the following: since the single particle energy does not depend on other particles and all particles are identical, I will calculate the partition function of a single particle as $Z_1=\displaystyle\frac{1}{h^3}\int e^{\frac{\vec{p}^2}{2m}}d^3qd^3p \cdot \Sigma_{\sigma} e^{-\mu_BH\sigma}$, meaning $Z_1=Z_{tr}\cdot Z_m$ as the produce of two partition functions. For the partition function of the system, since all particles are identical, $Z=(Z_{tr}Z_m)^N$ will hold. However, this assumes that particles are distinguishable.

If the partition function contained only the $Z_{tr}$ term, I would say the particles are indistinguishable and then I would have to divide by $N!$.

On the other hand, if the partition function contained only the $Z_m$ term, I would say that they are distinguishable.

So what about the product? I tend to think that the product is distinguishable because of the $Z_m$ term so it should be $Z=(Z_{tr}Z_m)^N$. Am I correct? What is the criterion for distinguishability in this case?

Comment: classic particles with spin?

Comment: I changed the title to avoid confusion. I meant that each particle has an intrinsic magnetic moment which under external field, adds a term in the Hamiltonian.

Comment: @Shing It is a frequently used improper extension of the meaning of the word *spin*. If you give a look at a statistical mechanics textbook, you'll find that dynamical variables of all variants of classical Ising models a called *spins*, even though classicl statistical mechanics  and classical Hamiltonians are used.

Comment: Why would you say that  particles are distinguishable if  the partition function contained only the $Z_m$  term?

Comment: @GiorgioP Well, I'm not sure they are. In similar examples that I have found, where the Hamiltonian depends only on the magnetic moments of the particles, they were are considered distinguishable. However, I'm not sure, that's why I posted the question.

Comment: Thinking about it, if two of these particles exchange momenta and magnetic moment orientation mutually, the Hamiltonian does not change. So isn't that the criterion for indistinguishability?